# Remove the text outside the first brackets in R

Tags: regex, r

I know that it was asked a lot of times, but I've tried to adapt the other answers to my need and I was not able to make it work using SKIP and FAIL (I'm a bit confused, I've to admit)

I'm using R actually.

The url I need to clean is:

```
url <- "posts.fields(id,from.fields(id,name),message,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0))"
```

and I need to retain only the content inside the first brackets that are always prefixed by the word "fields" (while "posts" may vary). In other words something like

```
id,from.fields(id,name),message,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

As you may see there're some nesting inside. But I eventually **could** change my source code to accept this string too (removing every parhentesis by every prefix)

```
id,from,message,comments,likes
```

I don't know on how to remove the trailing parhentesis which balances the first.

Answer (score 2):

If it's good enough to just remove everything up to and including the first open parenthesis and also remove the last close parenthesis and thereafter then:

```
sub("^.*?\\((.*)\\)[^)]*$", "\\1", url)
```

**Note:**

If it's good enough to just remove the first open parenthesis and last close parenthesis then try this:

```
sub("\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lazy `.*` instead of greedy:

```
sub(".*?fields\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", url)
[1] "id,from.fields(id,name),message,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recursive pattern:

```
sub("[^.]*+(?:\\.(?!fields\\()[^.]*)*+\\.fields\\(([^()]*+(?:\\((?1)\\)[^()]*)*+)\\)(?s:.*)", "\\1", url, perl=T)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC0qU9/1)

details:

```
# reach the dot before "fields("
[^.]*+             # all except a dot (possessive)
(?:                # open a non-capturing group
    \\.            # a literal dot
    (?!fields\\()  # not followed by "fields("
    [^.]*          # all except a dot
)*+                # repeat the group zero or more times

\\.fields\\(

# match a content between parenthesis with any level of nesting
(              # open the capture group 1
    [^()]*+    # 0 or more character that are not brackets (possessive)
    (?:        # open a non capturing group
        \\(    
        (?1)   # recursion in group 1
        \\)    # 
        [^()]* # all that is not a bracket
    )*+        # close the non capturing group and repeat 0 or more time (possessive)
)              # close the capture group 1
\\)

(?s:.*)        # end of the string
```

[Possessive quantifiers](http://regular-expressions.mobi/possessive.html) are used here to limit the backtracking when for any reason a part of the pattern fails.

Comment: "need to" seems like a rather strong claim, in light of the much simpler answers that were posted before yours...

Comment: This works really very well except that I need to do that only on pattern starting with (posts|comments).fields while this seems to do always...

Comment: @GabrieleB: in this case all you need is to add a lookbehind before `\\.fields`: `(?<=\\bposts|\\bcomments)`